# Yarn how to accept package user agreement

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

I trying to install the the highcharts-export-server package with the following command:

```
yarn global add highcharts-export-server
```

But this package required to answer son user agreement questions, but yarn does not allow me to answer this questions.

Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the answers to the setup questions as environment variables:

`ACCEPT_HIGHCHARTS_LICENSE=y HIGHCHARTS_VERSION=latest HIGHCHARTS_USE_STYLED=y yarn add highcharts-export-server`

For further details see their docs on [Using in Automated Deployments](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/blob/67a17aaa6dd912e9809fe766706ff1df52b843fa/README.md#using-in-automated-deployments).